# Point Domain Registered Through iPage to Heroku App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, dns, hosting

I've got a domain (and hosting account) with iPage.

I'd like to point this domain `example.com` and `www.example.com` to my heroku app - which is currently available at `example.herokuapp.com`.

I've set up a CNAME (Alias) as follows:

```
host: www
points to: example.herokuapp.com
```

I've gone through [Heroku's documentation for custom domain names](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains); however, I've been unable to make it work.

What do I need to do differently?

Comment: Does a `dig` (either via the CLI or [online](http://www.digwebinterface.com/)) against your CNAME return your Heroku domain? Most DNS providers take ~5 minutes (at most) to update their zone file, so if you checked immediately it may not work. Note that you can't CNAME your root `example.com` domain without CNAME flattening ([article here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/)) - something that not all DNS providers support.

Answer (score 1):

1. The reason you are not able to access your site at www.example.com even after setting up the DNS correctly is you have not updated your application setting inside Heroku. You need to provide Heroku with the web address want to host your site, this you can do inside your Application Settings page.
2. Heroku does not support apex domain so you might want to setup a redirect from `example.com` to `www.example.com`, I don't see why you would want to run your site on two web address. But you really want to run your site on two addresses you can try [zerigo dns](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/zerigo_dns) addon on heroku. Zerigo dns can also help you setup the redirect.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains

Comment: I've added my domain through heroku as I should have; however, it's still not working.

Comment: Sounds like either you DNS update is not working or you have a typo somewhere.